# Updating users location every x amount of seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to log the users location every x amount of seconds. In this specific code, it is 5 seconds. I am using watchPositionAsync. The code below I thought would log the latitude and longitude every 5 seconds however it does not log anything in the console at all.

I want to be sure it is updating and logging it in the console would confirm that. Let me know if you have any questions or need to see more code.

expo-location docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

function MyTabs() {

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = React.useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = React.useState(null);
  

React.useEffect(() => {
    
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        permissionAlert();
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        timeInterval: 5000,
        distanceInterval: 50
        
      },
        console.log('update location!', location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
      );
      setLatitude(location.coords.latitude)
      setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);

    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: And what is Location? What location library are you using? Can you link to their docs?

Comment: I have added a bit more code as well as added docs

Comment: The docs say that the second parameter is a callback. You haven't provided a function for the second parameter, just a function call which evaluates to `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the second parameter of watch position suppose to be a callback with the location object as the first arg

```
Location.watchPositionAsync({
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        timeInterval: 5000,
        distanceInterval: 50
        
      },
        location => {
            console.log('update location!', location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
            setLatitude(location.coords.latitude)
            setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information on the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationoptions)

Note that:

1. you should pass a callback as the second argument of `watchPositionAsync` as explained [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationwatchpositionasyncoptions-callback)
2. `timeInterval` is Android-only, so if you're testing it on iOS it won't work; moreover, that `timeInterval` is the **minimum** time that should pass, it doesn't notify you every 5 seconds, it's more like a throttle (https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#aa-throttle);
3. you set a `distanceInterval` of 50 meters... are you moving enough for it to notify you?